# Put variable into FOR..IN

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to implement [this](http://www.dbforums.com/showthread.php?1034420-How-to-Return-a-Value-from-PL-Sql-Script) example but I need to send argument to `t.sql` from user input, like this:

t.sql

```
set timing off
set feedback off
set pages 0
select sysdate from dual;
exit
```

batch file

```
SET /P %arg%="Please enter argument for t.sql: "
FOR /F "usebackq delims=!" %%i IN (`sqlplus -s u/p@db @t.sql %arg%`) DO set xresult=%%i
echo %xresult%
```

but sqlplus is not receiving %arg%

It seems very simple but how to correctly put contents of %arg% into IN (``) ?

Comment: `SET /P "arg=Please enter argument for t.sql: "`.  Only use the percent signs when you want to *retrieve* the value of arg, not when *set*ting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write it like that :

```
@echo off
SET /P "arg=Please enter argument for t.sql: "
echo %arg%
Pause
FOR /F "usebackq delims=!" %%i IN (`sqlplus -s u/p@db @t.sql %arg%`) DO set xresult=%%i
echo %xresult%
Pause
```